# Haskell Web Framework, snap: snap init fails

Tags: haskell-snap-framework

I have installed snap via:
`sudo apt install cabal-install`
`cabal install snap snap-templates`
then, I make a new directory in home for testing
`mkdir snap-test && cd snap-test`
`snap init`
but I get the error..

> error: unknown command "init", see "snap --help"

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Ubuntu is finding the wrong package.
It was finding an executable called 'snap' in /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin or wherever 'snap' was installed. Apparently, 'snap' is also a program.

By using this line:
`export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH`
We tell bash to look here first before looking in other places for executables.

Comment: where do you put the above line in? I am on MacOS and had put the line in /etc/.bash_profile (created my own) but I still get the same error

Comment: If your message was "error: unknown command "init"", then I would say that snap is not properly installed. Unless on MacOS there is also a package named snap (unlikely)?